# Can I add more than one field to a single attribute

Tags: java, variables, private, gosu, guidewire

I was wondering if it's possible to add 2 different attributes to a single attribute. For example I have two attributes:

```
private var modelYear:int as ModelYear
private var manufacturedCd:String as ManufacturerCd
```

I would like to put both of these attributes into one attribute called "personalVehicle". So then I can derive these values from personalVehicle on another class.

To clarify my question:

1. Can I add two attributes into one attribute called personalVehicle?
2. If so, how can I pull just the modelYear from the personalVehicle attribute on another class?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are using Gosu in one of the Guidewire's apps (hence the guidewire tag).

In these apps you have access to **gw.util.Pair** class which is basically a container for two values.

```
var personalVehicle = new Pair<Integer, String>(2010, "something")
```

You can access stored values through First and Second properties.

```
print(personalVehicle.First) //prints 2010
print(personalVehicle.Second) //prints "something"
```

**Please note that First and Second tell you nothing about what is stored inside these properties.** In your case (especially if you want to pass your personalVehicle to other classess) it may be better to define separate class storing modelYear and ManufacturerCd.

```
class PersonalVehicle {
    private var modelYear : int as ModelYear
    private var manufacturedCd : String as ManufacturerCd
}
```

Using such class would make your code more readable.